# How to find the row where the sum of all values in a column reaches a specified value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given data in a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE purchases (timestamp DATETIME, quantity INT)
```

I would like to find the point in time (i.e. the timestamp of the row) where the sum of the values in the quantity column passed a certain threshold value.

This is in MS SQL Server, and ideally I'd like to avoid using a cursor if possible.

Comment: Can you give sample data? Is this this SUM on a given timestamp, or a running SUM?

Comment: Is it a Heap, or do you have an index on (timestamp) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT timestamp, SUM(quantity)
FROM purchases
GROUP BY timestamp
HAVING SUM(quantity) > someValue
```

Or if it is a Running Sum

```
SELECT a1.timestamp
FROM purchases a1, purchases a2 
WHERE a1.quantity >= a2.quantity or (a1.quantity=a2.quantity and a1.timestamp = a2.timestamp) 
GROUP BY a1.timestamp, a1.quantity
having SUM(a2.quantity) >= someValue
ORDER BY a1.timestamp ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the smallest timestamp where the sum of the previous values is larger than the threshold:

```
select min(timestamp)
from purchases p
where (
  select sum(x.quantity)
  from purchases x
  where x.timestamp < p.timestamp
) > @threshold
```

However, this is not a very efficient query, so it might be better to use a cursor after all.

Comment: Assuming OP has an index on timestamp, and it is ascending, then MAX() not MIN().

Comment: Or just a change in operator from `<` to `>`.

Comment: Fine with me.  There is a boundary definition problem (due to OP not being entirely specific): the last row of the <= set, or the first row of the > set. But they can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005+ you could try this:

```
;WITH numbered AS (
  SELECT
    timestamp,
    quantity,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)
  FROM purchases
),
recursive AS (
  SELECT
    timestamp,
    quantity,
    rownum,
    runningsum = quantity,
    passed = CASE WHEN n.quantity < @threshold THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM numbered
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    n.timestamp,
    n.quantity,
    n.rownum,
    runningsum = n.quantity + r.runningsum,
    passed = CASE WHEN n.quantity + r.runningsum < @threshold THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM numbered n
    INNER JOIN recursive r ON n.rownum = r.rownum + 1
)
SELECT MIN(timestamp)
FROM recursive
WHERE passed = 1
```

Basically, same as [@Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216126/how-to-find-the-row-where-the-sum-of-all-values-in-a-column-reaches-a-specified-v/5216181#5216181)'s solution, only makes use of CTEs to avoid the need of triangular join.